# Google Maps API V2 showing blank white screen on mobile

Tags: google-maps-api-2

I made an app using Lynda's tutorial of Building Mobile Apps Using Google Maps API V2(http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Building-Mobile-Apps-Google-Maps-Android-API-v2/133347-2.html).
I am stuck on Chapter 2 ( Creating You First Map) . I followed each and everything but still my device shows a blank screen with Google Written in Bottom Left Corner and Zoom In and Zoom Out buttons.It looks like it is not able to load the map.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.map;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(servicesOK()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready To Map!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.avtivity_map);

        }
        else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean servicesOK(){
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

        return true;
    }
    else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
         dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't Connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }
        return false;

    }



}
```

AndroidManifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
          <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBdhCuM37w_myIbi87dMDwRnwd383UwXSk" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Avtivity_map.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me solve this. Why aren't maps coming on screen.
I am making a Google Science Fair project in which this app has a role to play.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you finally solve this somehow?